# How to open a new window in cocoa mac application with a button

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have to do a simple app, that when a button is pressed, a new window should appear.
I've tried with

```
- (IBAction)LanciaPavia:(id)sender {
    NSWindowController *controllerWindow = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"AOPAVIAWindowController"];
    [controllerWindow showWindow:self];
}
```

but the new window appears and immediately closes. What do I have to do? I don't know to proceed, and I'm new to the cocoa world!

Answer (score 3):

The key to the answer is scope:

```
- (IBAction)LanciaPavia:(id)sender {
    NSWindowController *controllerWindow = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"AOPAVIAWindowController"];
    [controllerWindow showWindow:self];
}    // controllerWindow goes out of scope
```

At the end of that scope the `controllerWindow` would go out of scope (I assume you are using ARC) and so the window controller be destroyed and the window closed.

Make it an instance variable and preferably one that is only created once.

Comment: If you look my code i have declared the same. I mean instance variable of window Controller. I am not getting what is different on your code? Can you explain??

Comment: @hussainShabbir I don't show the code for creating the instance variable, but what I've been trying to tell you all this time is that you need to guard against creating another window controller if one already exists; `if (!self.windowcontroller) { self.windowcontroller = /* alloc */; }`.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling a self before the controllerWindow

like so:

```
[self.controllerWindow showWindow:self];
```

Comment: What would lead you to the conclusion that that would help?

Comment: Since there are no other code mistakes and calling self could be the answer. As I can see for now we're working on a solution and you're just  commenting solutions with no added value.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to load the window is follow the below steps:-

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AOPAVIAWindowController.h"
@interface ARCAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSWindowController *windowController;
}
-(IBAction)loadWindowNew:(id)sender;
@property(readwrite,strong)NSWindowController *windowController;
@end

#import "ARCAppDelegate.h"

    @implementation ARCAppDelegate
    @synthesize arcWindowController;
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }
    -(IBAction)loadWindowNew:(id)sender
    {
        self.windowController=[[AOPAVIAWindowController alloc]init];
        [self.windowController showWindow:self];
    }
    @end
```

Now in your window contoller class write like this:-

```
#import "AOPAVIAWindowController.h"
@implementation AOPAVIAWindowController
-(NSString *)windowNibName
{
    return @"AOPAVIAWindowController";
}
@end
```

Comment: it says me that retain is unavaiable... What does it mens?

Comment: oh it means you are using ARC rt??

Comment: And what happens if `loadWindowNew:` is called again?

Comment: See in this loadWindowNew action method last line is written  [self.windowController showWindow:self]; it will open window only once. If you want to open multiple instance of window then use this  [self.arcWindowController loadWindow];

Comment: [self.arcWindowController loadWindow];  This will load multiple instances of window. Please try

Comment: @"trojanfoe" If you wanted to open multiple instances of window then need to use loadWindow  api if not then showWindow will be good to use.

Comment: Have you considered what happens when you reassign a pointer using ARC?  It deallocs the old instance which will cause the window controller to close the window.  The code you show will not work as you desire.

Comment: @"trojanfoe" if you have code please paste here i will sort out here. Because when i am using through arc my code is working fine without fail.

Comment: This code: `self.windowController=[[AOPAVIAWindowController alloc]init];` should not be called if `self.windowController != nil` else you will lose the reference to the previous window controller object.

Comment: Here the problem is when user is loading the window, it appears and immediately close. So the solution i had given in the above code. Now what else is required?

Comment: I am unwilling to discuss this any further.  I don't seem to be able to make myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your `controllerWindow` variable is a local to the `LaciaPavia:` method, so it's dealloced as soon as the method finishes execution. Try creating a property in the class containing `LaciaPavia:`. Then do something like the following:

```
- (IBAction)LaciaPavia:(id)sender {
    if (!_controllerWindow) {
        _controllerWindow = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"AOPAVIAWindowController"];
    }
    [[self controllerWindow] showWindow:self];
}
```